# Howto start/stop twisted TCP connection by ajax and get connection status

Tags: python, ajax, twisted, modbus

In twisted application I'd like to start/stop tcp connection (to modbus) via ajax POST. I have one button titled Connect or Disconnect depending of connection status.

Now my code looks like:

```
class ConnectHandler(Resource):

    modbus_connection = None

    def try_disconnect(self):
        log.msg('Disconnecting...')
        try:
            self.modbus_connection.disconnect()
        except:
            log.err()
        return self.modbus_connection.state

    def try_connect(self):
        try:
            framer = ModbusFramer(ClientDecoder())
            reader = DataReader()
            factory = ModbusFactory(framer, reader) # inherits from ClientFactory
            self.modbus_connection = reactor.connectTCP(ip, 502, factory)
        except:
            log.err()
        return str(self.modbus_connection.state)

    def render_POST(self, request):
         if self.modbus_connection and \
            self.modbus_connection.state == 'connected':
            return self.try_disconnect()
        else:
            return self.try_connect()
```

Now I get 'connecting' when connection is starting and 'connected' when stopping connection.
I would like wait with response until connection is established or abolished and return connection status (connected or disconnected + optionally error description).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Delaying a response is usually a matter of returning a `defer` from the `render` method which you then have called by whatever you're waiting on. In this case I think you'd need to set up your client protocol for the modbus connection to call a defer you pass to it somehow before calling `reactor.connectTCP`.

Have you given up on using the websockets you mentioned in your previous question?
[How to asynchronously read data via modbus/TCP and send them to web](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12053599/267781)

Websockets seem to me like an effective approach to essentially proxying a connection between a browser and a modbus server.

Comment: Thank you. No I didn't give up with websockets. Just want to add modbus ip address option and start/stop listen functionality :). I want to write simple code for good start, but I have used some of Your code so Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

If you use the endpoint API instead, you'll get a Deferred back that fires with the connected protocol instance once the connection has been established and that protocol instance has been created and connected:

```
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint

e = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, ip, 502)
d = e.connect(factory)
def connected(protocol):
    print 'Connection established, yay.'
    # Use `protocol` here some more if you want,
    # finish the response to the request, etc
d.addCallback(connected)
```